# SQLite GROUP BY 2 Tabelas e SUM entre valores das tabelas

Tags: sql, sqlite

Olá, eu tenho as seguintes tabelas e estou utilizando o SQLite:

```
Transação cartão:
id, valor, data
1, 20, Janeiro
2, 40, Janeiro
3, 10, Fevereiro

Transação banco:
id, valor, data,
1, 10, Janeiro
2, 10, Janeiro
3, 5, Fevereiro
4, 45, Março
```

Eu preciso que o retorno seja o agrupamento por mês com o retorno da soma dos valores ordenado pela data crescente o decrescente. No caso do exemplo acima, o retorno teria que ser:

```
Valor, data
80, Janeiro
15, Fevereiro
45, Março
```

Considerando que pode ter datas que tem em uma tabela e em outra não.

Como seria o comando para o retorno esperado?

O que eu tentei foi algo do tipo abaixo, porém, o resultado está sendo ele somar todos os valores para todas as linhas.

```
SELECT SUM(b.valor + c.valor) valor, b.data, c.data  FROM cartaoTransacoes as c, bancoTransacoes as b GROUP BY c.data, b.data ORDER BY c.data, b.data ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como as tabelas não tem um campo em comum, o que você pode fazer é um UNION para juntar as consultas em separado, e sobre este resultado fazer o agrupamento. Sua consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT data, sum(valor) as valor FROM (
SELECT data, valor
FROM cartaoTransacoes 
UNION
SELECT data, valor
FROM bancoTransacoes 
) GROUP BY data
```

Mais informações:

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-union/

Comment: Obrigado! Era isso mesmo que eu precisava. Estou começando agora com sql e saber que é possível fazer essa consulta de um SELECT dentro de um FROM vai me ajudar muito!